# Erro ao imprimir membro de struct: request for member in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct

Eu tenho a seguinte `struct`:

```
typedef struct{
    int Numerador ;
    int Denominador ;
} TNumeroRacional ;
```

Nessa função eu peço para o usuário inserir 2 numeradores e denominadores para formar 2 números racionais.

```
void Atribuir (TNumeroRacional* num,TNumeroRacional* num2,int Numerador,int Denominador){
 printf(" a: Atribuir valores para os campos.\n");
 printf("Primeiro numero racional:");
 printf(" Por favor, insira os valores: \n Numerador: ");
 scanf("%d",&num->Numerador);
 printf(" Denominador: ");
 scanf("%d",&num->Denominador);
 printf("Segundo numero racional:");
 printf(" Por favor, insira os valores: \n Numerador: ");
 scanf("%d",&num2->Numerador);
 printf(" Denominador: ");
 scanf("%d",&num2->Denominador);
 printf("Numero racional 1: %d/%d \n",num.Numerador,num.Denominador);
}
```

Quando tento imprimir qualquer elemento, me aparece:

> ```
> error: request for member 'Numerador' in something not a structure or union
> error: request for member 'Denominador' in something not a structure or union
> ```

Eu não sei se meu erro está na atribuição, mas a mensagem de erro só aparece na linha de printf.

Comment: Por favor coloque o código inteiro do programa, para que possa ficar mais clara a sua duvida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este problema eu não vi acontecer mas pode ser porque o problema está na chamada e isto não foi colocado na pergunta, tinha outro erro que corrigi no `printf()` final:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int Numerador;
    int Denominador;
} TNumeroRacional;

void Atribuir(TNumeroRacional *num, TNumeroRacional *num2, int numerador, int denominador) {
    printf(" a: Atribuir valores para os campos.\n");
    printf("Primeiro numero racional:");
    printf(" Por favor, insira os valores: \n Numerador: ");
    scanf("%d", &num->Numerador);
    printf(" Denominador: ");
    scanf("%d", &num->Denominador);
    printf("Segundo numero racional:");
    printf(" Por favor, insira os valores: \n Numerador: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2->Numerador);
    printf(" Denominador: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2->Denominador);
    printf("Numero racional 1: %d/%d \n", num->Numerador, num->Denominador);
}

int main(void) {
    int numerador = 0, denominador = 0;
    TNumeroRacional num, num2;
    Atribuir(&num, &num2, numerador, denominador);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/zQOQxr). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gghaxaje-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/AccessMember.cs).

Comment: além disso na verdade eu também não precisava ter chamado os ints numerador e denominador, mas essencialmente era isso mesmo! obrigada.

Comment: Sim, eu apenas achei que ia fazer algo com eles depois.